# strange dynamic_cast behavior when target variable has same name with source variable

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, dynamic-cast

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    int foo = 321;
};

struct Bar: public Foo {
    int bar = 123;
};

int main() {
    const Foo* ptr = new Bar();
    std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
    {
        const Bar* ptr = dynamic_cast<const Bar*>(ptr);
        std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
    }
    {
        const Bar* ptr2 = dynamic_cast<const Bar*>(ptr);
        std::cout << ptr2 << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the program output the following lines if compiled with `-O2`:

```
0x613c20
0
0x613c20
```

and if without `-O2`, it's like:

```
0x614c20
0x400b70
0x614c20
```

In both case, the second line seems problematic, when the target variable name conflicts with source variable name of `dynamic_cast`. I tried both gcc 4.8 and 5.2 and also clang 11.0.3 .

Anyone has clue about this?

Comment: GCC 5.2 [warns for this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/czLzJG). Strangely, Clang doesn't.

Comment: What happens is basically the same like `int x = x;`. Your variable `ptr` is set to its own value, because the local `ptr` variable hides the outer `ptr` completely.

Comment: IMHO, this is unrelated to `dynamic_cast`. It's about eclipsing variables: [demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fca864698e10addd). With sufficient warning level, g++ warns about this: [demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a199c80bf3d9efc).

Comment: Don't do that. <g>